# Need help with regular expression and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've following problem: I use a clone script to clone input fields which are used for cms options. Depending on the field name the option arrays are created in the db.

I have following field at the moment:

```
options[categories][1][3]
```

and want to increase the first number by using a counter variable like:

```
options[categories][2][3]

options[categories][3][3]
```

...

However I'm not familiar with regular expressions so I hoped someone could provide a str.replace code which helps me to replace the first number with my counter variable.

Thanks in advance!

.......
Code:
.......

At the moment it looks like:

```
if ( $(clone).attr('name') ){
                newid = $(clone).attr('name');
                var position = newid.lastIndexOf("[");

                newid = newid.substring(0, position)+ '[' + (counter +1) + ']';
                $(clone).attr('name', newid);
            };
```

Html field:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="options[categories][1][3]">
```

3 is the category id, 1 is the option I need the category for. The clone script would produce:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="options[categories][1][4]">
```

at the moment - but I need:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="options[categories][2][3]">
```

I think it's a regex problem because the easiest solution would be to search for [categories][anyvalue] and replace it with [categories][counter]

Comment: This is not a REGEX issue. Post some code more similar to your situation. We can't work with the current data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I think it is one because my clone scripr reads all input field attributes (name, id, etc.) and adds a counter variable to it so that my options are saved in different array fields. I.e. i've the option array with subarrays like "categories" - by cloning one field I want to create a new subarray i.e. [1], [2], etc. based on the input fields name

Comment: In your official post please. And add your HTML too ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to replace the first number in brackets. Like this:

```
if ( $(clone).attr('name') ) {
    var newid = $(clone).attr('name');
    newid = newid.replace(/\[[0-9]*\]/, '[' + (counter + 1) + ']');
    $(clone).attr('name', newid);
};
```